# How do I get Stanford Core NLP Commerical Liocense?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I want to estimate the cost of using Stanford Core NLP into my proprietary software. Where can I find the info?

Answer (score 1):

> For distributors of proprietary software, CoreNLP is also available
> from Stanford under a commercial licensing You can contact us at
> java-nlp-support@lists.stanford.edu.

The information about is from [here](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/#license).